why sheafification does not commute with direct sum
Let $\mathscr F_i$ be sheaves on $X$. By universal property of sheafification we know taking sheafification is left adjoint and thus preserves all colimits. I thus think taking sheafification should commute with direct sum. As a result，if the sheafification of direct sum of sheaves is direct sums of sheafification of sheaves and it is equal to direct sum of sheaves. This means direct sum of sheaves is a sheaf. But this is clearly not true. For an easy counter example，one can think sheaves of abelian groups defined on a discrete topological space with infinitely many points. Let $i_x：x\rightarrow X$ be the inclusion and let $\mathscr A_x$ be constant sheaf. Let the index set $I=X$. Define $F_x=i_{x*}(A_x)$，then $\operatorname{Colimit} \mathscr F_x(U) = \oplus_{x\in U} A_x$. Suppose colimit  is a sheaf then consider the collection of all singleton set covering and the short exact sequence associated to the definition of sheaf，we get $\operatorname{Colimit} F_x（U）= \Pi_{x\in U} A_x$ but as the index set $X$ is infinite the direct sum and direct product of abelian groups do not coincide.

In my argument above, where went wrong?


Sorry it does not compile well. I will change it tomorrow.

Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498298/products-and-sums-of-sheaves where Roland shows an example of the presheaf direct sum failing to be a sheaf.

You're right that $\prod_{x\in U}A_x$ is not the direct sum of the Abelian groups $A_x$, not in general. But this isn't a contradiction. $U\mapsto\bigoplus_{x\in U}A_x$ is not the direct sum of the $\mathcal{F}_x$ in the category of sheaves. Sheafification does commute with direct sum, the direct sum is just not what you seem to think it is. Really, you're just observing that colimits of sheaves aren't computed set-theoretically, levelwise for each open, the way colimits of presheaves are

The key problem lies in that: what is the direct sum in the category of sheaves? The claim that taking sheafification should commute with direct sum is true, but direct sum is defined by a universal property instead of a formal construction such as taking direct sum of abelian group term-wisely. The correct direct sum in the category of sheaves should be the sheafification of the direct sum in the category of presheaves.
To make the explaination more explicit, we take the concept of cokernel as an example. Given a morphism $f: F\rightarrow G$ of sheaf, the same symbol $\operatorname{Coker}(f)$ represents different things in the category of presheaves and sheaves, just like what happens in the case of direct sum.
